# Can someone help me make a timer that works

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to make some kind of timer that is triggered by a user and it's updated every minute. Here's my code! The timer never goes down, even if I added an interval that is removing 30k miliseconds from the difference.

````
        let x = await msg.channel.send('Calculating...')
        async function countdownTimer() {
            let difference = 1800000;
            let remaining = "Monster Respawned!";

            setInterval(() => {
                difference = difference - 30000;
            }, 30000);

            if (difference > 0) {
              const parts = {
                days: Math.floor(difference / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)),
                hours: Math.floor((difference / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24),
                minutes: Math.floor((difference / 1000 / 60) % 60)
            };

            remaining = Object.keys(parts)
                .map(part => {
                    if (!parts[part]) return;
                    return `${parts[part]} ${part}`;
                })
                .join(" ");
                x.edit(`Respawn:${remaining}`);
            }
        }   
        countdownTimer()

        setInterval(() => {
            countdownTimer()
        }, 60000);

    ```
````

Comment: sorry i'm really dumb...i just had to get the difference thing out of that shit... sorry guys ))

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
let div = document.querySelectorAll(".out")[0];
let end = Date.now() + 30 * 60 * 1000; // end in 30 minutes

function countdownTimer() {
  let remaining = "Monster Respawned!";

  difference = end - Date.now();
   if (difference > 0) {
     const parts = {
        days: Math.floor(difference / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)),
        hours: Math.floor((difference / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24),
        minutes: Math.floor((difference / 1000 / 60) % 60)
     };

   remaining = Object.keys(parts)
    .map((part) => {
      if (!parts[part]) return;
      return `${parts[part]} ${part}`;
    })
    .join(" ");
  div.innerText = `Respawn:${remaining}  ${difference}`;

  // recursion:
  setTimeout(() => {
    countdownTimer();
  }, 5000);
} // if
}

// start:
countdownTimer();
```

See: [codepen](https://codepen.io/krocon/pen/dyYrvWQ)